# Docker daemon is running but it cant connect

Tags: ubuntu, docker, daemon

I´m trying to launch Docker, I have Docker running inside a Virtual Machine in Virtual Box. I´m using the last version of Ubunty (I have download this today), and my SO Mac OS.

I´ve followed this steps to install docker: http://docs.docker.com/linux/step_one/

Right now I´m trying to check if the install was good.

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

I get "Cannon connect to the docker daemon... "

I check if the Daemon is running:

```
$ ps aux | grep docker
```

I get a PID number and all that info...

Why it cannot connect with the daemon?

Comment: Did you try "sudo docker run hello-world"?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend following instead "[Mac OS X](http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/)"

Once **[docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)** is installed, create one machine

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
eval "$(docker-machine env default)"
```

Then docker commands should work.

Comment: @LeonardoCavani Simply unzip https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.5.1/docker-machine_darwin-amd64.zip anywhere you want, and add it to your $PATH

Comment: @LeonardoCavani All docker machine releases: https://github.com/docker/machine/releases. No setup required.

Answer (score 3):

I have problems with Docker on OS X, which seems to be unstable, but it works fine for me on Ubuntu Linux (as a regular OS without Virtual Machine). If you're using Ubuntu, make sure you're typing **sudo** before each docker command.

Instead of:

```
docker run hello-world
```

simply type:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

In my case it fixed problems with error "Cannon connect to the docker daemon... ", but **only on Ubuntu**.